# Database null returning as string null in soap xml

Tags: xml, livecycle

I'm using Livecycle for a web service tier.

If there is a null in the database, the nodes have a string 'null' in them.

how can I make sure that I strip out the 'null' values form the nodes and also tell if the value of the node is really 'null'?

Comment: I need more info. What are you trying to accomplish and how? What does the null-nodes in the generated XML look like? Is the xml going to populate an xdp?

Comment: <MyName>null</MyName> is an example of a 'null' tag. So when I try and load the object from the result xml, it see the 'null' as string null and not db null. Some of the datatypes are numeric.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`IsNull('','')` is added to the SQL. That way the database catches the true db null and makes it a blank.